# PHP if-statement ignored when header(Location: xxx) is inside

Tags: php, redirect, header, if-statement

I have a strange problem. There is an if-statement at the top of my page that seems to be ignored when a header(location: xxx) commmand is inside of it.

```
$check = $authorisation->check(); 
// i know this results in true by echoing the value 
// (you've got to believe me on this one)

if(!$check){
    // redirect to message
    header("Location: message.php");
    exit;

}else{
    // do nothing, continue with page
}
```

This ALWAYS redirects to the message.php page, no matter what the outcome of $authorisation->check() is!

Strange thing is, when I comment out the header-command, and put echo's in the if-statement for verification, all works as to be expected:

```
    $check = $authorisation->check(); // true
    if(!$check){
        // redirect to message
        echo "you are not welcome here";
    }else{
        echo "you may enter";
    }
```

The result is "you may enter";

This also works as expected:

```
    $check = true;
    if(!$check){
        // redirect to message
        header("Location: message.php");
        exit;

    }else{
        // do nothing
    }
```

This only redirects to the message page when $check = false;

Last funny thing is that I experience the problem only on 1 server, same script works flawlessly on testserver.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry.. not clear on what is happening..?

Comment: suggestion: also write `exit();` after `header();`

Comment: Added "exit;" after redirects (thanks for the suggestion), but that makes no difference.

Comment: As stupid as it may sound, did you make a var_dump($check) on the _failing_ server?

Comment: That shows 'bool(true)' as expected

Comment: It seems to be impossible. Any chance that the page is called twice? Did the error reporting give you some hints?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error reporting didn't provide any more information. The problem only exists immediately after logging in. When I browse to the same page after the first load (after the unwanted redirect), the problem is gone, and I see the page I want to see...

Comment: Do you make other redirects on other pages with a missing exit? Could they interfere? I suspect the problem lies outside this page (or the code we can see here).

Comment: If i had to guess, i'd guess you were dealing with a race condition during the login process.  (Login stuff on another page sets a session variable, then bounces to the main page...but the redirect happens so fast that the session file hasn't been updated yet.)  I've seen it a bunch of times...and usually a `session_write_close` before sending the redirect header makes it go away.

Answer (score 4):

you should always run `exit` after you are finished with headers so that the transfer is faster and more stable for the browser.

Try this way:

```
if( ... )
{
     header("Location: message.php");
     exit;
}

// ...
```

Please read the comment for other tip's on why this is a good idea.

Comment: I wouldn't mention faster and stable as arguments first, but the fact that all the code below will still execute before the header resolves. Which can cause unexpected behavior if you don't know.

Comment: This is true, but only the browser will use the headers for the redirect, so even if there is content below, the browser will not fetch it and usually close the connection, it only fetches the HEAD, checks everything, then the BODY, but your are 100% correct, he should always take that into consideration as it could be private data.

Answer (score 4):

Call the **exit** function after redirecting to another page, otherwise the following code will be executed anyway.

```
if(!$check){
  // redirect to message
  header("Location: message.php");
  exit;
}else{
  // do nothing, continue with page
}
// the following code will be executed if exit is not called
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put `error_reporting(-1);` you will see something new. On one of your servers, the PHP error reporting is set to lower level.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of error is often caused by content being sent to the browser before the header function is called.

Even if you don't think you are sending content, if your file starts with a space or blankline before "< ? php" then you will hit an error - this is often quite a subtle thing to notice/find.

Output buffering can allow you to call the header function even after you've "sent" content out - this is probably why the page works on one server and not another.

Answer (score 0):

**suggestion:**

- write [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top and
- also write [`exit();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after `header();`
- debug with `error_reporting(-1)` as suggested in one answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you are calling header('Location: blahblah') somewhere else in the code. check it.