# header('location:...) doesnt behave right in combination with if clause

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, header

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
  if(verify_post_data() == 'success')
  {
    if(do_something_with_verified_post_data() == 'success')
    {
    //do something else
    header('location: success.php');
    }
  }
  header('location: failure.php');
}
```

I want to process the data a user has posted in multiple steps (first verify if everything's correct, then do something with the data).

If verification of the post data and doing something with it has been successful, I want to redirect the user to success.php

If verification failed, or if doing something with the data failed, I want to redirect to failure.

here's what's happening:

when i remove the header(...) functions by commenting and instead I say

```
//header('location: success.php');
echo 'success!';
```

and

```
//header('location: failure.php');
echo 'failure!';
```

My script will print "success!failure!" if my data was correct and no errors happened when doing something with the data. Makes perfect sense... Because the echoing of success didn't interrupt the script, failure will still be displayed.

so when I uncomment the success header (failure header stays commented), it does indeed send me to success.php

if I then also uncomment the failure header, it will now - even upon success - send me to failure.php.

How is that possible?

I expect the header function to interrupt the script and ignore any code that comes after it. Is my assumption wrong? Do I have to somehow exit the script manually?

Doesn't php process the code line by line? or does it do the headers in the curly brackets last and other headers first, or what?

Or should this not be happening and I must be having an error somewhere else?

Comment: Put an `exit;` after `header();`

Comment: make sure you have all the tree files in the same folders

Comment: the problem is not, that the header function doesn't do anything because I have output before calling header, also i am not being redirected to a 404. From the two header options I have I am being called to the wrong one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes php executes line by line.
There may be some error in your posted data,
If you write two headers of location ,the first one will get executed,
But also the rest of the script gets executed,
To avoid this situation,you need to call **exit;**Or just use the die() function if the user posted wrong data.
also try this code below:

```
if(do_something_with_verified_post_data() == 'success')
{
 //do something else
 header('Location: success.php');
 exit;
}
else
{
 header('Location: failure.php');
 exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The header function doesnt interrupt the script and ignore any code that comes after it. So in all your cases Location header is sent as `location: failure.php`
It will be a better idea to place `location: failure.php` in else part. if you have firebug installed , you can check the response headers in the 'net' panel of firebug

Comment: you are right. but i cant use an else part if i dont want to duplicate my code unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use `echo` before and after `header`. And use `exit` after `header`.

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
  if(verify_post_data() == 'success')
  {
    if(do_something_with_verified_post_data() == 'success')
    {
       //do something else
       header('location: success.php');
       exit();
    }
  }
  header('location: failure.php');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: That's it, I have to use exit... I wasn't echoing anything though, that was not the problem...

Answer (score 1):

First,
Do not use `echo/setcookie()` before calling `header()`.

Second,
You need to **abstract** a redirection, like this:

```
function redirect($location){

  if ( ! headers_sent() ){
     header(sprintf('Location : %s', $location));
     exit;
  }
}


if( ! empty($_POST) ) // isset() is good for array keys, not for this one itself
{
  if(verify_post_data() == 'success')
  {
    if(do_something_with_verified_post_data() == 'success')
    {
     //do something else
     redirect('success.php');
    }
  }
   redirect('failure.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

A [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149941/php-if-statement-ignored-when-headerlocation-xxx-is-inside?rq=1) lead me to the answer

**I have to call exit(); after calling header()...**

I just tried it, and when calling the exit function, everything works. So apparently my assumption

> I expect the header function to interrupt the script and ignore any code that comes after it.

is wrong...!