# if / elseif `isset` multiple submit inputs doesn't work

Tags: php, isset

I have several submit inputs  (buttons) on a page, with the following `isset`conditions:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'noranTelChecks' ] ) ) { // user requested noranTelCheck sheet
    header( 'location: noranTelChecks.php' );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST[ 'juniperChecks' ] ) ) { // user requested noranTelCheck sheet
    header( 'location: juniperChecks.php' );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST[ 'mpr95001Checks' ] ) ) { // user requested noranTelCheck sheet
    header( 'location: mpr95001Checks.php' );
} // close IF
```

But no matter what button is clicked the page is always redirected to the link referred to by the first `IF` condition. If I change the order of the links referred to, it is always the link in the first condition that the page gets redirected to.

What could be the problem with the above code causing this issue, as I have done this in the past on other pages and it has worked fine?

Comment: Check your `$_POST` in all cases

Comment: While I don't know what the cause is, you could try to use a variable for the location target (`$location`) within your if/elseif, then just make one single call to `header('location: ' . $location);` outside of it - maybe that helps somehow?

Comment: Dit you give a name to your input button? only  the clicked input should be send if u give a name. See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929471/how-do-i-use-two-submit-buttons-and-differentiate-between-which-one-was-used-to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP if-statement ignored when header(Location: xxx) is inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149941/php-if-statement-ignored-when-headerlocation-xxx-is-inside)

Comment: According to the linked question (possible duplicate), you might need to add `exit();` after the calls to `header()`.

Comment: @u_mulder and @Incognito thanks for pointing me in the direction of the problem. It turns out the first submit button had the same name as a radio button that had its `value=1` and so I guess the `isset` condition was always being met no matter what button is clicked.

Comment: btw, always use exit to "commit" your header("location: ...");

Comment: Can you provide the HTML form too? Maybe a var_dump($_POST) out would be great also.

Comment: It means that `noranTelChecks` is never empty, please check your html form, I think there is a mistake

Answer (score 1):

I guess your buttons have values set for example

```
<input type="submit" id="noranTelChecks" name="noranTelChecks" value="Button 1"/>
```

so you could use the value instead of name or id. The code would be as follow

```
if ( isset( $_POST["Button 1"] ) ) 
{ 
    header( 'location: noranTelChecks.php' );
}
```